# need a bootstrap progress bar. Can anyone help me?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please provide sample links to implement simple bootstrap progress bar. Please help me out.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_progressbars.asp

Answer (score 2):

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) if your scroll down you will see a progress bar section or you can select it from the menu on the right just choose progress bar and it will show you all progress bar examples bootstrap has to offer.

Hope this helped :)

Comment: Upvote answer if this helped @SangeetaMandal